# Idiomatische Übersetzung für "Enter, X"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom

Im englischen gibt es ein Idiom welches grob der Struktur folgt:

> (Long explanation of a thing.)
> Enter, (something that is relevant for or related to the thing).

Zum Beispiel:

> It's such a difficult thing to find compentent help when you have problems that only experts can solve.
> Enter, Stackexchange.

Ich bin nicht sicher woher dieses Idiom stammt, bzw. was die Herkunft des Wortes "Enter" hier ist (kommt es von "enter a room" oder von "enter key" oder ...?). Es kann bedeuten, *hier kommt die Lösung*, oder *in dieser Situation wird Element so-und-so in die Mischung geworfen* (kann die Situation verschlimmern/verbessern/unberührt lassen) oder *hier kommt ein gutes Beispiel für das zuvor beschriebene*.

Gibt es eine entsprechende Floskel im deutschen?

Comment: Ich würde davon abraten das zu übersetzen. Eine entsprechende Floskel gibt es nicht, da das Meme im Englischen entstanden ist. Wenn man es in dem Sinne verwenden möchte, würde ich den englischen Gebrauch empfehlen.

Comment: @infinitezero: Ehm: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/59440/447

Comment: Und was willst du mir jetzt damit sagen? Eine Übersetzung und Entsprechung ist sicher möglich, aber dem habe ich auch nie Widersprochen...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Das Idiom "Enter" stammt aus der Theatersprache. Shakespeares Macbeth [beginnt](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/full.html) etwa mit

> SCENE I. A desert place.
>
> Thunder and lightning. Enter three Witches

Enter ist hier eine Regieanweisung und bedeutet so viel wie

> Betritt die Bühne

Das Gegenteil ist

> Goes out/Exit - Geht ab

Eine idiomatische Übersetzung wäre demnach eine aus der Theatersprache. Ich meine auch des öfteren schon

> Auftritt: xxx

gehört zu haben, was mE eine passende Übersetzung ist.

Alternativ auch die bekannten

> Ihr Auftritt xxx

bzw

> Ihr Auftritt bitte, xxx

was Anspielungen auf die früher bekannten Sendungen "Ihr Auftritt Al Mundy" und die Kultursendung "Ihr Auftritt bitte" sind.

Comment: It seems to me the title of the movie *Enter the Dragon* uses the same idea. The titles of the movie in other languages don't match up though, so it looks like this particular phraseology is unique to English, at least outside of a script.

Comment: Das klingt extrem plausibel, und ich meine auch schon mal "Auftritt: soundso" gehört zu haben.

Comment: Typsch wären IMO kursive Anweisungen in Klammern als Teil der Dialoge: "Franz: (_tritt ein_) Ich grüße euch!".  Und für "Exit" gibt es zumindes die Entsprechung "(_ab_)".

Answer (score 1):

*X tritt auf* is eine Regieanweisung, die man in deutschen Dramen finden kann.

Beispiel aus *Die Räuber* von Schiller, zweiter Akt:

> FRANZ VON MOOR. [langer Monolog]
> *Hermann tritt auf.* Ha! Deus ex machina! Hermann!
> HERMANN. Zu Euren Diensten, gnädiger Junker!